# When does the multiplier ideal sheaf non-zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, complex-geometry

I am reading Demailly's lecture notes and just noticing the concept of multiplier ideal sheaf. Let's say $\varphi$ is a plurisubharmonic function that is not $-\infty$ on a complex manifold $X$. Let $\Omega\subset X$ be an open subset. and we associate the ideal subsheaf $\mathcal{I}(\varphi)\subset\mathcal{O}_{\Omega}$ which consists of germs of holomorphic functions $f\in\mathcal{O}_{x,\Omega}$ such that $|f|^2e^{-2\varphi}$ is integrable in an open sets around $x$. I wonder if there are any necessary or sufficient condition that $I(\varphi)$ is nonzero.

Even if we look at the simple case for the open unit disk in $D=\{z:\|z\|<1\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ and we pick any plurisubharmonic function $\varphi$, is there always a way to construct such holomorphic function $f$ explicitly, such that
$$\int_D|f|^2e^{-2\varphi}<\infty$$